# Show that Y is complete space

Tags: functional-analysis

> If $X,Y$ are normed space, and $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is Banach space, then $Y$ is complete space.

I know that, if $X$ is a normed space and $Y$ a Banach space, then $\mathcal{B}(X,Y)$ is Banach, but how prove the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(You must assume $X\neq 0$.)

Let $f$ be a nonzero bounded linear functional from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ (existing by Hahn-Banach), and let $x_0\in X$ be such that $f(x_0)=1$.  Suppose $Y$ is not complete and let $(y_n)$ be a nonconvergent Cauchy sequence in $Y$.  Let $(T_n)$ be the sequence in $B(X,Y)$ defined by $T_n(x)=f(x)y_n$.  Then $\|T_n-T_m\|=\|f\|\|y_n-y_m\|$, so $(T_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.  Note that $T_n(x_0)=y_n$, so $(T_n(x_0))$ does not converge, which implies that $(T_n)$ does not converge in $B(X,Y)$.  Hence $B(X,Y)$ is not complete, and by contraposition this shows that if $B(X,Y)$ is complete (and $X\neq 0$), then $Y$ is complete.